# How to convert MP3 into VOX file format in linux / unix

Tags: audio, conversion, mp3, format

I want to know how do I convert an mp3 file to [vox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogic_ADPCM) file format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [Sound eXchange aka SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).  Here's an example of converting WAV to VOX ([source](http://old.nabble.com/sox-doesnt-convert-wav-to-adpcm-vox-correctly-any-more-td14282153.html)):

```
sox input.wav -r 8000 -c 1 output.vox vol 1.0 polyphase stat
```

See the [SoX manpage](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) and [supported file formats](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxformat.html) documentation.

Note that the general *sox* syntax is:

> sox [*global-options*] [*input-format-options*] infile1 [... infile2]
>    [*output-format-options*] outfile [*effect* [*effect-options*]

So in the above example, `-r 8000 -c 1` are format options for the output VOX file.

You probably won't need input file options for MP3 data since SoX can read that from the file header.

Answer (score 1):

[SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) supports vox format.